# C# XML conversion

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string containing fully formatted XML data, created using a Perl script.

I now want to convert this string into an actual XML file in C#.  Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(... your string ...);
doc.Save(... your destination path...);
```

see also

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d5awd922%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can load a string into an in-memory representation, for example, using the LINQ to SQL `XDocument` type. Loading string can be done using `Parse` method and saving the document to a file is done using the `Save` method:

```
open System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);
doc.Save(fileName);
```

The question is why would you do that, if you already have correctly formatted XML document?
A good reasons that I can think of are:

- To verify that the content is *really* valid XML
- To generate XML with nice indentation and line breaks

If that's not what you need, then you should just write the data to a file (as others suggest).

Answer (score 4):

Could be as simple as

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test.xml", "your-xml-string");
```

or

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test.xml", "your-xml-string", Encoding.UTF8);
```